Express and ytdl-core YouTube Video Info and Download API Not Working as Expected
I'm trying to create an API using Node.js with Express and ytdl-core to fetch YouTube video details and provide a download link. But somehow when i press the download Button the page just starts loading and nothing happens. Here is my code:
Backend
const express = require('express');
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();
const port = 5000;

app.use(cors());

app.get('/video-info', async (req, res) => {
  const videoUrl = req.query.url;
  if (!ytdl.validateURL(videoUrl)) {
    return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Invalid YouTube URL' });
  }

  try {
    const info = await ytdl.getInfo(videoUrl);
    const formats = ytdl.filterFormats(info.formats, 'videoonly');
    const videoDetails = {
      title: info.videoDetails.title,
      duration: info.videoDetails.lengthSeconds,
      thumbnail: info.videoDetails.thumbnails[0].url,
      formats: formats.map(format => ({
        itag: format.itag,
        quality: format.qualityLabel,
        container: format.container,
      })),
    };
    res.json(videoDetails);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Failed to fetch video details' });
  }
});

app.get('/download', (req, res) => {
  const videoUrl = req.query.url;
  const itag = req.query.itag;

  if (!ytdl.validateURL(videoUrl)) {
    return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Invalid YouTube URL' });
  }

  res.header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="video.mp4"');

  ytdl(videoUrl, { filter: format => format.itag == itag }).pipe(res);
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on http://localhost:${port}`);
});


Frontend
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function Home() {
  const [url, setUrl] = useState('');
  const [showPanel, setShowPanel] = useState(false);
  const [thumbnailUrl, setThumbnailUrl] = useState('');
  const [videoTitle, setVideoTitle] = useState('');
  const [videoDuration, setVideoDuration] = useState('');
  const [resolutions, setResolutions] = useState([]);

  const isValidYouTubeUrl = (url) => {
    const pattern = /^(https?:\/\/)?(www\.youtube\.com|youtu\.?be)\/.+$/;
    return pattern.test(url);
  };

  const fetchVideoDetails = async (videoUrl) => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:5000/video-info?url=${encodeURIComponent(videoUrl)}`);
      const data = await response.json();
      setVideoTitle(data.title);
      setVideoDuration(formatDuration(data.duration));
      setThumbnailUrl(data.thumbnail);
      setResolutions(data.formats);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching video details:', error);
    }
  };

  const formatDuration = (durationInSeconds) => {
    const minutes = Math.floor(durationInSeconds / 60);
    const seconds = durationInSeconds % 60;
    return `${minutes} min ${seconds} sec`;
  };

  const handleDownload = () => {
    if (isValidYouTubeUrl(url)) {
      fetchVideoDetails(url);
      setShowPanel(true);
    } else {
      setShowPanel(false);
      alert('Please enter a valid YouTube URL.');
    }
  };

  const downloadVideo = (itag) => {
    const downloadUrl = `http://localhost:5000/download?url=${encodeURIComponent(url)}&itag=${itag}`;
    window.location.href = downloadUrl;
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Enter YouTube URL here"
        value={url}
        onChange={(e) => setUrl(e.target.value)}
      />
      <button onClick={handleDownload}>Download</button>

      {showPanel && (
        <div>
          <div>
            <img src={thumbnailUrl} alt="YouTube Thumbnail" />
          </div>
          <div>
            <h2>{videoTitle}</h2>
            <p>Duration: {videoDuration}</p>
            <div>
              <h3>Available Resolutions:</h3>
              {resolutions.map((res, index) => (
                <div key={index}>
                  <p>{res.quality}</p>
                  <button onClick={() => downloadVideo(res.itag)}>Download</button>
                </div>
              ))}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Home;


My problems are that the page is just loading and not downloading anything also somehow i made it work in the past but then there were errors with the encoder.

the page is just loading which page? the two endpoints shown return JSON and a video ... there is no "page" to speak of. Also, what encoder? there isn't one of those either in the code you've shown

I would have helped if your frontend code was written in Vanilla Js. Check your backend code and see if you can play the url of the video on a browser. If it's playable then it can be downloadable.

Can you share a full working example? Maybe on StackBlitz...
